# firestore returns empty array while using date filter in capacitor js

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, google-cloud-firestore, capacitor

This below code i used to retrieve data from firestore

it works good in desktop

```
myfirebasedb=[]

await db.collection("myfirebasedb")
.where("date", ">=",moment(payload.from_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
.where("date", "<=",moment(payload.to_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
      myfirebasedb=_.map(querySnapshot.docs,(doc)=>{ return {firebase_id:doc.id,...doc.data()}})
})
.catch((error) => {
    reject(error)
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

See the docChanges it gives the four objects ,this exactly  what i want but same code in capacitor js act like a strange ,i also posted mobile  debug image below

[image]

Getting empty result here
Same code in capacitor js returns nothing

[image]

i am only facing when implementing where tag in firestore it gives empty result in capacitor js but desktop works what i want.

my firebase data

[image]

updated:date filter works if i put single where in mobile

```
await db.collection("myfirebasedb")
.where("date", ">=",moment(payload.from_date).format())
```

Comment: "DD-MM-YYYY" formatted dates will not sort the way you expect every time.  Expect these queries to fail eventually, because the sort order of these strings is not truly chronological.  But without seeing your data and how that matches your actual query filter strings, we can't tell what's going on here.  Everything is speculative.

Comment: i attached firebase data format ,i am using "DD-MM-YYYY" format in firebase db.

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying that you shouldn't use that format if you want to sort dates.  Those strings will not sort chronologically.  YYYYMMDD will sort the way you expect. If you need to display something different, reformat it on the client app.  Note also that we still can't see your input data.  It's all hidden behind variables.  We have no idea what `payload` contains.

Comment: Got it,thank you

Comment: error still not resolved ,i tried timestamp too but working only on desktop and  capacitor js always return empty array and i also tried chronologically order. here i am getting actual result only on desktop , it looks date format is right for me but code act as strange.

Comment: hi,today,i checked firestore query works smoothly in mobile when i use single "where" but if i put two where in query it returns empty in mobile but  in desktop even i use two where  condition it works. what is happening exactly here in mobile ?